# Select a feature in a layer group in QGIS by coordinates

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I have the following layers inside a layer group 'Parcels'
[image: layergroup]

I have created a Plugin that will determine a coordinate (Coordx,Coordy) based on a user input and then pan/zoom the map to the coordinate (Note: Coordx and Coordy are Qstrings). What I want it to do is select a feature that contains the coordinate and zoom/pan to the extent of that feature.  The feature could be in any of the 12 vector layers shown in the picture.  If there is no feature that contains the coordinate in any of the layers, then the plugin will zoom/pan to the coordinate instead at some predetermined extent based on the variable 'scale'. I have included the code for the pan/zoom function for reference

```
            # Create new extent rectangle
        rect = QgsRectangle(
          float(Coordx) - scale,
          float(Coordy) - scale, 
          float(Coordx) + scale,
          float(Coordy) + scale)
        mc=self.iface.mapCanvas() 
        # Set the extent to our new rectangle
        mc.setExtent(rect)
        # Refresh the map
        mc.refresh()
```

Comment: I would recommend using a QgsFeatureRequest() in layer.getFeatures(). I'll post an answer later if you still need help.

Comment: I would like a detailed answer since I have minimal coding experience and would like to implement the solution.  Also note that the layers are not really Parcels1, Parcels2, etc, but have different names corresponding to the county they are in e.g. Fred, Alamaney, Duncan.  I assume they need to be evaluated on an individual basis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would iterate over a list of layers using a filter. This assumes everything is in the same CRS.

```
# create a rectangle to sort features by. Qgis will find overlapping features
# it's ok that xmin & xmax are the same and ymin & ymax are the same.
# typecast to float may be unnecessary 
filterRect = QgsRectangle(float(Coordx),float(Coordy),float(Coordx),float(Coordy))

projectRoot = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
parcelGroup = projectRoot.findGroup("Parcels") # replace with actual group name

featFound = False

for lyr in parcelGroup.findLayers():
    try:
        # get feature iterator and select first one that overlaps
        featFound = lyr.layer().getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest(filterRect)).next()
        lyr.layer().select(featFound.id())

    except StopIteration:
        # if none do just move on
        pass

if featFound: # will still be false if no feature was found
    mapExtentRect = featFound.geometry().boundingBox()
else:
    mapExtentRect = QgsRectangle(
        float(Coordx) - scale,
        float(Coordy) - scale, 
        float(Coordx) + scale,
        float(Coordy) + scale)

mc=self.iface.mapCanvas() 
# Set the extent to our new rectangle
mc.setExtent(mapExtentRect)
# Refresh the map
mc.refresh()
```

if for any reason you want to manually define a list of layers to search instead of using a group you can create a list of the layers by name:

```
searchLayers = ['layer1','layer2','layer3'...]
for layerName in searchLayers:
    layer = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName( layerName )[0]
    # will return a list of layers matching name so select the first ([0])
    ...
```

Comment: new error
       featFound = lyr.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest(filterRect)).next()
   AttributeError: 'QgsLayerTreeLayer' object has no attribute 'getFeatures'

Comment: Oops typo. Mean lyr not layer. Fixed above

Comment: Perhaps I should have mentioned that Coordx and Coordy are Qstrings: Had to change filterRect to             filterRect = QgsRectangle(
                    float(Coordx),
                    float(Coordy), 
                    float(Coordx),
                    float(Coordy))                                              edited my above comment with a new error   --almost got this!

Comment: added fix. needed to use lyr.layer().getFeatures... to reference actual layer. my apologies.

Comment: No worries, I appreciate the help.  Got a new error now  mapExtentRect = featFound.boundingBox()
AttributeError: 'QgsFeature' object has no attribute 'boundingBox'

Comment: featFound.geometry().boundingBox()... edited above

Comment: This is working.  One last bit, can you please fix the filterRect in your code to match my comment#2 so others will get the correct version?  Also, if a feature is found, can you add the code to select that feature?  Thank you very much for this!

Comment: there you go. remember to upvote a working answer :)

Comment: Please change lyr.select(featFound.id()) to lyr.layer().select(featFound.id()) and this problem is solved and ofc i will upvote it :) thank you for your help!